# Using getElementById to find child element

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Javascript, I need to select child elements with `getElementById()`:

```
#topbarsection li a {}
```

I've tried this:

```
topbarsection = document.getElementById('topbarsection>li>a');
```

and this:

```
topbarsection = document.getElementById('topbarsection li a');
```

Comment: You have to use `querySelector` to select elements using CSS selector and not `getElementById`. `getElementById` selects elements based on `id`.

Comment: @Harry or run a bunch of different selectors and tests to filter down a list of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `querySelectorAll` for such things:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#topbarsection > li > a');
```

Comment: This answer shouldn't even work, as the css selector is meant to be `#topbarsection li a` not `#topbarsection > li > a`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one would use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll), it accepts css selectors and returns a list of elements,

```
document.querySelectorAll('#topbarsection li a');
```

would return an array of `<a>` elements which are [descendants](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) of `<li>` elements, in turn descendants of `#topbarsection`.

You can access the elements as you would the items a normal array,

```
document.querySelectorAll('#topbarsection li a')[0]
```

Is the first element found, `[1]` the second, etc.

Because of this, we can apply changes to each of the elements in turn; let's say we want to set all their `target` attributes to `"_blank"`, we can do that using a for loop:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#topbarsection li a');

for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
}
```

Ta - da!

There is also the less commonly used [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector), which works similarly to `document.getElementById` in that it only returns a single element.

```
document.querySelector('.header') === document.querySelectorAll('.header')[0]
```

It returns the first element matched.